# How to detect file encoding in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, file, encoding

How to detect which encoding was defined to a file?

I want something like this:

```
fs.getFileEncoding('C:/path/to/file.txt') // it returns 'UTF-8', 'CP-1252', ...
```

Is there a simple way to do it using a nodejs native function?

Comment: `fs` is a native module of `node`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [encoding-japanese](https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding-japanese) package, and it worked well.

Example :

```
var encoding = require('encoding-japanese');
var fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('file.txt');
console.log(encoding.detect(fileBuffer))
```

Available Encodings:

- 'UTF32' (detect only)
- 'UTF16'
- 'UTF16BE'
- 'UTF16LE'
- 'BINARY' (detect only)
- 'ASCII' (detect only)
- 'JIS'
- 'UTF8'
- 'EUCJP'
- 'SJIS'
- 'UNICODE' (JavaScript Unicode Array)

It can be used both in node or browsers. Oh... And it has **zero dependency**.

Comment: I tested this with some simple test strings containing German umlaut characters, and it did not work. I would recommend jschardet, which seems to work much better.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a "*native Node.js function*" that can do this.

The simplest solution I know is using an npm module like [detect-file-encoding-and-language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-file-encoding-and-language). As long as the input file is not too small it should work fine.

```sh
// Install plugin using npm

$ npm install detect-file-encoding-and-language
```

```js
// Sample code

const languageEncoding = require("detect-file-encoding-and-language");

const pathToFile = "/home/username/documents/my-text-file.txt"

languageEncoding(pathToFile).then(fileInfo => console.log(fileInfo));
// Possible result: { language: japanese, encoding: Shift-JIS, confidence: { language: 0.97, encoding: 0.97 } }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use an npm module that does exactly this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding

You can use it like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const detectCharacterEncoding = require('detect-character-encoding');

const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('file.txt');
const charsetMatch = detectCharacterEncoding(fileBuffer);

console.log(charsetMatch);
// {
//   encoding: 'UTF-8',
//   confidence: 60
// }
```

Comment: The project you mention does not work on Windows. Is there another tool that works well?

Comment: It doesn't appear to install well in Linux either.  That bug was reported in 2017. I would consider this a waste of time.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I've been using, for a while now.  YMMV.
Hope it helps.

```
var fs = require('fs');
...
getFileEncoding( f ) {
```

```
    var d = new Buffer.alloc(5, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    var fd = fs.openSync(f, 'r');
    fs.readSync(fd, d, 0, 5, 0);
    fs.closeSync(fd);

    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
    var e = false;
    if ( !e && d[0] === 0xEF && d[1] === 0xBB && d[2] === 0xBF)
        e = 'utf8';
    if (!e && d[0] === 0xFE && d[1] === 0xFF)
        e = 'utf16be';
    if (!e && d[0] === 0xFF && d[1] === 0xFE)
        e = 'utf16le';
    if (!e)
        e = 'ascii';

    return e;
```

}

Comment: Depending on use case & how sure I need to be -- BOM sniffing suggests not very -- I'd probably start with `e = 'utf8'`, remove utf8 check, then run the rest of the ladder without the `!e &&` preamble (adding some `else`s/ternaries). Duck typing by BOM is a very **practical** idea for, say, reading files! [@Falaen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66782376/1028230), when no BOM or obvious tipoff, sniffs the whole file [looking for telltale signs](https://github.com/gignupg/Detect-File-Encoding-and-Language/blob/main/src/config/languageObject.js), which is clever, but perhaps overkill.

Comment: Yeah, since [UTF-8 is essentially a superset of at least 7-bit ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Comparison_with_other_encodings), if you're just looking for a practical "how should I read this?", you don't lose any utility with `return d[0] === 0xfe && d[1] === 0xff ? "utf16be" : d[0] === 0xff && d[1] === 0xfe ? "utf16le" : "utf8";`, I don't think.

Answer (score 3):

What about [`jschardet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jschardet)? By the time of writing it has hundreds of thousands of downloads per week, it should work

```js
var jschardet = require("jschardet")

// "àíàçã" in UTF-8
jschardet.detect("\xc3\xa0\xc3\xad\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3")
// { encoding: "UTF-8", confidence: 0.9690625 }

// "次常用國字標準字體表" in Big5
jschardet.detect("\xa6\xb8\xb1\x60\xa5\xce\xb0\xea\xa6\x72\xbc\xd0\xb7\xc7\xa6\x72\xc5\xe9\xaa\xed")
// { encoding: "Big5", confidence: 0.99 }

// Martin Kühl
// jschardet.detectAll("\x3c\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x3e\x4d\x61\x72\x74\x69\x6e\x20\x4b\xfc\x68\x6c\x3c\x2f\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x3e")
// [
//   {encoding: "windows-1252", confidence: 0.95},
//   {encoding: "ISO-8859-2", confidence: 0.8796300205763055},
//   {encoding: "SHIFT_JIS", confidence: 0.01}
// ]
```

Comment: for Angular user,  here is a useful example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-detect-encoding

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Mark Longmire's answer, here is a more recent (TypeScript) version - note that it will only work if there is an optional BOM character which seems to be a limitation of a lot of solution on this topic:

```
import { closeSync, openSync, readSync } from 'fs';

/**
 * Get the encoding of a file from an optional BOM character.
 *
 * This will only work if there is a BOM characters, and they are rarely used since they are optional.
 *
 * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
 *
 * @param filePath - The path of a file on which to check encoding.
 *
 * @returns The file encoding if found, otherwise "unknown".
 */
function getFileEncoding(filePath: string): string {
  const byteOrderMark = Buffer.alloc(5, 0); // Generate an empty BOM.
  const fileDescriptor = openSync(filePath, 'r');
  readSync(fileDescriptor, byteOrderMark, 0, 5, 0);
  closeSync(fileDescriptor);

  let encoding: string;

  if (
    !encoding &&
    byteOrderMark[0] === 0xef &&
    byteOrderMark[1] === 0xbb &&
    byteOrderMark[2] === 0xbf
  )
    encoding = 'utf8';
  if (!encoding && byteOrderMark[0] === 0xfe && byteOrderMark[1] === 0xff) encoding = 'utf16be';
  if (!encoding && byteOrderMark[0] === 0xff && byteOrderMark[1] === 0xfe) encoding = 'utf16le';
  if (!encoding) encoding = 'unknown';

  return encoding;
}
```